# How to send http request to a server on host inside wasm plugin of envoy?

Tags: webassembly, envoyproxy

Inside my wasm filter, I tried to use proxy-wasm-cpp-sdk to send a http request to a server on host machine. My C++ wasm code is:

```cpp
auto r = httpCall(remote_addr,
                    {{":method", "GET"}, {":authority", "wasm_plugin"}}, "",
                    {}, 1000, callback);
```

But `r` is always return as `WasmResult::BadArgument`.

The argument `remote_addr` is set with json plugin configuration. The following is my `envoy.yaml` file:

```yaml
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      # ...
  clusters:
  - name: httpbin
    connect_timeout: 30s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: httpbin
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: httpbin
                port_value: 80
  - name: rule_server
    connect_timeout: 30s
    type: STATIC
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: rule_server
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 11111
```

The `127.0.0.1:11111` is the server address I want to contact with. I had tried to set `remote_addr` as `rule_server`, `127.0.0.1:11111`, `outbound|11111||rule_server`, `outbound|11111||rule_server.static`. They all don't work. What's the right uri for calling `httpCall`?